# VHDL Uninitialized out port has no driver

Tags: vhdl

I´m making a Parallel-in, Parallel-out register with async clear and sync with falling edge, I´ve made the bistable, and I´ve made this for the register:

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE ieee.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
ENTITY registro_PP IS
    GENERIC (num_bits : NATURAL);
    PORT (
        clock, clr : IN STD_LOGIC;
        ent_datos : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR((num_bits - 1)DOWNTO 0);
        sal_datos : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ((num_bits - 1)DOWNTO 0)
    );
END registro_PP;

ARCHITECTURE con_generate OF registro_PP IS
    COMPONENT biestable_D_con_Clr IS
        PORT (d, clock, clr : IN STD_LOGIC;
            q : OUT STD_LOGIC);
        END COMPONENT;
        SIGNAL conec : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ((num_bits - 1)DOWNTO 0);
        SIGNAL salida : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ((num_bits - 1)DOWNTO 0);
    BEGIN
        B : FOR I IN 0 TO num_bits - 1 GENERATE
            U : biestable_D_con_Clr
            PORT MAP(
                d => conec (i), clock => clock, clr => clr, q => 
                salida (i)
            );
        END GENERATE;
END con_generate;
```

I got this test too:

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE ieee.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
ENTITY regPPtest IS
END regPPtest;
ARCHITECTURE regPPArch OF regPPtest IS
    COMPONENT registro_PP IS
        GENERIC (num_bits : NATURAL);
        PORT (
            clock, clr : IN STD_LOGIC;
            ent_datos : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR((num_bits - 1)DOWNTO 0);
            sal_datos : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ((num_bits - 1)DOWNTO 0)
        );
    END COMPONENT;
    SIGNAL entrada : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR((5 - 1)DOWNTO 0);
    SIGNAL salida : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR((5 - 1)DOWNTO 0);
    SIGNAL poner_cero : STD_LOGIC;
    SIGNAL reloj : STD_LOGIC := '0';
    CONSTANT periodo : TIME := 10 ns;
    FOR U1 : registro_PP USE ENTITY WORK.registro_pp (con_generate);
    BEGIN
        U1 : registro_PP
            GENERIC MAP(5)
            PORT MAP
            (clock => reloj, clr => poner_cero, ent_datos => entrada, sal_datos => salida);
            reloj <= NOT reloj AFTER periodo/2;
            entrada <= "00000", "00001" AFTER 8 NS, "00011" AFTER 18 NS, "00111" AFTER 26
                NS, "01111" AFTER 36 NS, "11111" AFTER 46 NS, 
                "11110" AFTER 56 ns, "11100" AFTER 66 ns, "11000" AFTER 87 ns;
                poner_cero <= '1', '1' AFTER 11 NS, '0' AFTER 47 NS, '0' AFTER 58 NS;
END regPPArch;
```

The problem comes when I try to simulate it, I got this warning

```
 # ** Warning: (vsim-8683) Uninitialized out port /regpptest/U1/sal_datos(4) 
 has no driver.
 # 
 # This port will contribute value (U) to the signal network.
 # ** Warning: (vsim-8683) Uninitialized out port /regpptest/U1/sal_datos(3) 
 has no driver.
 # 
 # This port will contribute value (U) to the signal network.
 # ** Warning: (vsim-8683) Uninitialized out port /regpptest/U1/sal_datos(2) 
 has no driver.
 # 
 # This port will contribute value (U) to the signal network.
 # ** Warning: (vsim-8683) Uninitialized out port /regpptest/U1/sal_datos(1) 
 has no driver.
 # 
 # This port will contribute value (U) to the signal network.
 # ** Warning: (vsim-8683) Uninitialized out port /regpptest/U1/sal_datos(0) 
 has no driver.
 # 
 # This port will contribute value (U) to the signal network.
```

I´ve been looking for the error in the code for hours, trying to change things but I couldn´t fix it, so I hope someone can help me.

Comment: sal_datos is neither the actual on the instantiated component nor assigned a value. It has do driver (nothing is assigning a value to it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems quite simple. You defined `conec` and `salida`, but never attach anything to it. Just add the declarations:

```
conec <= ent_datos;
sal_datos <= salida;
```

in entity `registro_PP`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you didn't connect anything to sal_datos, that's why it is not initialized. Actually, this is also the case for ent_datos (inside entity).